# An odd number of reputation points from edits?

Tags: discussion

Recently I hit the 500 edits mark before reaching 2000 reputation points.

There is a limit of 1000 reputation points that can be acquired with edits, thus my subsequent edits do not add reputation points.

The interesting thing is: my last edit for which I got points gave me only +1. It means that immediately before I must have had 999 points from edits.

How is that technically possible?

[image]

All edits give +2 reputation. And if posts are deleted, reputation points are also recalculated, but the actual number should always remain even.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/users/457662/techraf?tab=reputation says all your edits gave you +2. Did you get downvoted somewhere?

Comment: No, they don't influence the +1, but the achievements icon might show +1, if you downvoted something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You hit the daily rep cap on [March 7](https://askubuntu.com/users/457662/techraf?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=2). As a result, one edit on that day only got you a +1:

[image]

That left +1 for the edit rep limit, which you hit today.

Comment: Finally it makes perfect sense. Thank you. I'll sleep better now. :)